# How can I have a service account impersonate another service account? (Node.js)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api-nodejs-client

I authenticate by setting the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to the path to a key for my App Engine service account (e.g. `example@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`).

If a calendar is shared directly to the App Engine service account, I can do just do this:

```
let googleCalendar = google.calendar({
  version: 'v3',
  auth: new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'],
  })
});
```

But I want users to share their calendar with a different service account I have, `google-calendar@example.iam.gserviceaccount.com`. So I want the App Engine service account to impersonate the `google-calendar` account. I have tried this (and a few other minor variations):

```
let googleCalendar = google.calendar({
  version: 'v3',
  auth: new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    clientOptions: {
      subject: 'google-calendar@uniserval-app.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
    },
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'],
  })
});
```

I get a 401 error: `Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.`

I tried making my App Engine service account a Member on the `google-calendar` service account and granting it various Roles  such as `Service Account User` and `Service Account Token Creator` - but nothing changes.

I suspect the code is right and I just don't have the right Roles configured... but at this point I've been searching how to do this for 2 days and I can't find any documentation on exactly how to do this.

Comment: Double check that you have assigned the role `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser` to the service account assigned to App Engine. The error message indicates that you have not done this correctly. Next, what roles have you assigned to the `google-calendar` service account that allows access to calendar?

Comment: Here is how I assigned the Role: https://i.imgur.com/QiKyENw.png As for how `google-calendar` has access to Calendar is because in Google Calendar I share calendars with that service account email. But that parts not the problem, that works.

Comment: Why not grant the App Engine service account permission to the calendar instead of trying to impersonate a service account?

Comment: The #1 reason is because I already have calendars from multiple accounts shared with that service account. In my case it wouldn't be too difficult to get those users to edit the permissions of their calendars - but what if it had already been used hundreds of times? Mainly I just want to know how to do it because the docs say it's possible. The previous way I was doing it was to have a `secret.json` from my `google-calendar` account and deploy that with my app. Having my App Engine service account able to impersonate that 2nd service account instead just seems cleaner.

Comment: Actually, assigning a service account to App Engine with the right permissions to calender is cleaner. However, you have two areas that I mentioned that cause this problem. One or both are an issue for you.

Comment: What do you mean "assign a service account to App Engine"? As far as I know, App Engine has automatic access to the default service account and there's no way to change which service account it uses. I can manually create keys for other service accounts and share them with my app but I was already doing that. My point was to not have to manage secrets - by just using the default app engine service account.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207954/discussion-between-kenmore-and-john-hanley).

Comment: Are you a G-Suite admin? Might have to set up domain wide delegation. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax looks correct, just that you appear to have misunderstood which email address to set as the subject. The subject is the user account on whose behalf you wish to act.

```
new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
  clientOptions: {
    subject: 'someone@yourdomain.com'
  },
  scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'],
})
```